# animate elements of two grid view items android

Tags: android, animation, gridview

i have got two GridView with only TextView and on the click of text on any of the gridview item the text is replaced in secondary gridview (its like swapping) i want to show the transition like text is moving from one place another.

Comment: you are looking for [translate animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

Comment: yeah but thing is i can translate two textviews as i have the position of it !! but as gridview i can have the position of current view but how can i get the position of view to whom i would translate my current view